# I can't get my custom SurfaceView on top in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I have 3 views:

1. GLSurfaceView
2. Custom SurfaceView
3. View

   - The GLSurfaceView is at the bottom
   - The Custom SurfaceView should be above and on the top
   - The View is above and on the bottom

This is my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GameGlSurfaceView gameGlSurfaceView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gameGlSurfaceView = new GameGlSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(gameGlSurfaceView);

        View hudView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        addContentView(hudView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        View inpudPadView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input_pad, null);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams inpudPadViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        inpudPadViewParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        addContentView(inpudPadView, inpudPadViewParams);
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class SurfacePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    Context context;
    Bitmap bitmapTest;
    MyThread mythread;

    public SurfacePanel(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrSet   ) {
        super(ctx, attrSet);

        context = ctx;

        bitmapTest = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmapTest.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
    }

    void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTest, 50, 10, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mythread = new MyThread(holder, context,this);
        mythread.setRunning(true);
        mythread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mythread.setRunning(false);
        boolean retry = true;

        while(retry) {

            try {
                mythread.join();
                retry = false;
            }

            catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="de.batechniks.surfaceviewtest.MainActivity">

    <de.batechniks.surfaceviewtest.SurfacePanel
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="left">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bt_down"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

The result is: I can see the GLSurfaceView and i can see the view above on the bottom. 
On the top, i only see the textview "Large Text". The SurfaceView is not shown. 
When i uncomment `setContentView(gameGlSurfaceView)`, the SurfaceView is shown.

The main problem is to show the SurfaceView, the second problem will be to get the SurfaceView transparent.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you also give us the filenames of the layout xml files that you have provided? Also where is the code with commented `setContentView(...)`

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I added the setContentView in my code example.

Comment: Bit of confusion on language -- `setZOrderOnTop()` uses "on top" like you use "above".  I think. Whatever the case, try using `setZOrderOnTop()` on the Surface that's supposed to be in front of everything, as you get undefined behavior with two overlapping Surfaces at the same Z-order. Try clearing it with `canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)` (note the blend mode -- want to set the pixels, not blend them into the previous contents).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the method

```
this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

in your constructors.

It's recommended to do constructors in custom views like this

```
public SurfacePanel (Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public SurfacePanel (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public SurfacePanel (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

@TargetApi(21)
public SurfacePanel (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    if(!isInEditMode()) {
        this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, thats the solution